# Convert old "+" Join to SQL Server syntax?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm old school and have always used the "+" sign to represent outer, but this sql isn't working in sql server.  Can someone help me convert the following sql into the new "left outer join" format.

```
select frdonmst.FRID, 
       fradrmst.adrseq, 
       fax.phone   as fax, 
       phone.phone as phone 
from   frdonmst, 
       fradrmst, 
       frphnmst fax, 
       frphnmst phone 
where  frdonmst.frid = fradrmst.frid 
       and frdonmst.adrseq = fradrmst.adrseq 
       and ( frdonmst.frid = fax.frid(+) 
             and frdonmst.adrseq = fax.adrseq(+) 
             and fax.phtyp(+) = 'FAX1' ) 
       and ( frdonmst.frid = phone.frid(+) 
             and frdonmst.adrseq = phone.adrseq(+) 
             and phone.phtyp(+) = 'D1' )
```

Comment: NB - Old school in this case means you used Oracle before the ANSI standards.

Comment: if this had been posted to the c# crowd you would have probably got told to use [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) . The sql crowd are such a nice bunch though ....look at all the answers

Answer (score 5):

I'll give it a shot, but I've never seen a plus sign used in that capacity.  : )

```
SELECT a.FRID
    , b.adrseq
    , fax.phone AS fax
    , phone.phone AS phone
FROM frdonmst a
JOIN fradrmst b
    ON a.adrseq = b.adrseq
LEFT JOIN frphnmst fax
    ON a.frid = fax.frid
    AND a.adrseq = fax.adrseq
    AND fax.phtyp = 'FAX1'
LEFT JOIN frphnmst phone
    ON a.frid = phone.frid
    AND a.adrseq = phone.adrseq
    AND phone.phtyp = 'D1'
```

P.S. Having just typed this out by hand, I'd politely recommend using words to name things.

Comment: @user1475911, the old way has given inaccurate results as far back as SQL Server 2000 because it is ambiguious and is sometimes interpreted as a cross join. Implicit joins in general are a SQL antipattern, but the outer ones arent even guaranteed to work correctly at all even when the author didn't make a mistake like an accidental cross join.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
select 
frdonmst.FRID, 
fradrmst.adrseq, 
faxTable.phone as fax, 
phoneTable.phone as phone 
FROM (((frdonmst LEFT JOIN fradrmst ON frdonmst.adrseq = fradrmst.adrseq and frdonmst.adrseq = fradrmst.adrseq)
                 LEFT JOIN frphnmst AS faxTable ON frdonmst.frid = faxTable.frid AND frdonmst.adrseq = faxTable.adrseq)
                 LEFT JOIN frphnmst AS phoneTable ON frdonmst.frid = phoneTable.frid AND frdonmst.adrseq = phoneTable.adrseq)
WHERE faxTable.phtyp='FAX1' AND phoneTable.phtyp='D1'
```

Comment: I'm sure you don't need the `(`s in your query.